# Storing FB.api output

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm making a FB.API call in order to get a user's likes, I managed to see the likes as an array output in the JavaScript console, by console.log(likes).

However, I need a way to store this likes output, in order to use it again later in an algorithm, I tried inserting the output to a variable, however it doesn't work, here is the code that I tried:

```
var x;
function customFunction(likes) {
    console.log(likes) // Works, In the console I see Array[20], when each array member contains page name, categories etc...

    x=likes; // doesn't work
    document.write(x); //doesn't work
}

function get_user_likes(){
    FB.api('/me/likes',function(response){   
                 customFunction(response['data']);
           }
     );             
};
```

How can I store the output?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "doesn't work"? Do you get an error message?

Comment: where do you want to store it? in a variable? in a database? your question is way too broad.